# Server Object Extension doesn't work

Tags: arcgis-server, c#, arcgis-9.3

I built a server object extension in C# and Visual Studio 2010, using the ESRI sample for the Spatial Query SOE as a starting point.

(see [the page on resources.esri.com](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/adf/dotnet/developer/samples/Web_Applications/ArcGIS_Spatial_Query_SOE/C194F684-F51E-43FA-BF19-632ED33987AA.htm))

The SOE never displays a property page in ArcCatalog or in Server Manager. If I enable it, it won't allow the map service to start, saying that the CLSID for the MapServer is not registered.

I think this is a bogus message, but I can't debug this - it doesn't even hit write any of my log messages to the server log. All the libraries I use (interfaces, extension, property page, server manager and register) have all been registered and GAC'd. The property page class shows up in Categories.exe and the assemblies all show up in the assembly folder.

It seems like there's some unstated step or steps that I haven't followed, but I can't find much on this. Has anybody actually built a working SOE? Any suggestions?

Comment: Hev you compiled project with target x86 (not any platform)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [10.0 documentation for this sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000003q2000000), the steps are a bit more readable (and likely still applicable).

Comment: Thanks, Kirk. I'm in the middle of upgrading several servers to 10.0, so I haven't looked at it yet. The 9.x server samples do look like they were written by underwear gnomes.

Comment: @Tim, you have no idea, Step 1. Write Doc, Step 2. Try to Create Demo for Doc, Step 3. ???? Step 4. Profit! This is the ESRI business model...

Answer (score 0):

Is it a MSD map service? Does [this](http://viswaug.wordpress.com/2009/09/29/black-magic-behind-the-msd-map-services/) help any?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't thought to mention that. It's a MapServer service with an MXD document. I'm having enough trouble without trying out MSDs. :)

Answer (score 0):

The part where you're supposed to register the SOE with the MapServer can also be done using the [SOEXplorer tool](http://viswaug.wordpress.com/soexplorer/). It doesn't seem like it is working for ArcGIS Server 10 yet though.

I couldn't have been developing SOE without this tool.